# Python - Replace value in a file with re

Tags: python, regex

I have this file:

```
......
# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.2.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
otheraddress - this line is an example192.168.2.2
......
```

I want to replace the address ip and have this code.

```
import re

def get_value(filepath, regex):
    f = open(filepath, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        match = re.search(regex, line)
        if match:
            return(match.group(1))
    f.close()

def new_value(filepath, regex, value, newvalue):
    f = open(filepath, 'r')
    filedata = f.read()
    f.close()
    newdata = filedata.replace(value, newvalue)
    f = open(filepath, 'w')
    f.write(newdata)
    f.close()

def network():
    filepath = '/etc/network/interfaces'
    regex = 'address\s(.*)'
    ipaddr = get_value(filepath, regex)
    newipaddr = input('Dirección ip [' + ipaddr + ']: ')
    new_value(filepath, ipaddr, newipaddr)
```

If I execute my code, the filedata.replace from new_value() replace the line otheraddress from my file because also matching the ipaddr value.
I have tried using re.search () in new_value to use an regex and replace only the valid line but I don't get run because I need write changes on file and read file line by line for apply the regex to a lines.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Start your regex with a '^' to indicate a start of line

Comment: Hey rfkortekaas, I think what I need is something like this (if match:, line.replace(value, newvalue)), but doesn't work. I haven't idea why. I tried the ^ but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: After looking back over your code you had a couple other issues.  The method below will allow you to line by line read the file, make the replacements if necessary, and write the new data back to the file when finished:

```
import re

def network():
    filepath = '/etc/network/interfaces'
    filedata = []
    regex = r'^address ((\d+\.?)+)'

    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            match = re.match(regex, line)
            if match:
                ipaddr = input('Dirección ip [' + match.group(1) + ']: ')
                line = line.replace(match.group(1), ipaddr)
            filedata.append(line)

    with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(filedata)
```

I also made use of a [context manager](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) to handle the files instead of explicitly opening and closing them.

Comment: Thanks for this great solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly reworked version of your code that uses the 'search' regular expression again to do the replacement:

```
import re

def get_value(filepath, regex):
    f = open(filepath, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        match = re.search(regex, line)
        if match:
            return(match.group(1))
    f.close()

def new_value(filepath, regexsearch, regexreplace):
    f = open(filepath, 'r')
    filedata = f.read()
    f.close()
    newdata = re.sub(regexsearch, regexreplace, filedata, count=1, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    f = open(filepath, 'w')
    f.write(newdata)
    f.close()

def network():
    filepath = '/etc/network/interfaces'
    regexsearch = r'^(address\s)(.*)$'
    ipaddr = get_value(filepath, regexsearch)
    newipaddr = input('Dirección ip [' + ipaddr + ']: ')
    regexreplace = r'\g<1>' + newipaddr
    new_value(filepath, regexsearch, regexreplace)
```

It will only replace the first instance found in the file, if you want to replace all instances remove the `count=1`

Comment: Thanks for you response but in other moment I need change more values and aren't in order. Then I can't select 3 or more with count. The solution of Jkdc works for me.

Comment: No problem, I was trying to keep as closely as possible to your existing code- starting again from scratch allows for a much better solution :)

Comment: I will rewrite the code because I do not have anything yet. ;)